# MYSQL column alias on select not working when using Count

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join, alias

I have to similar columns on two joined tables with the name "plays", I want to differentiate them, but I get "Unknown column 'p.plays' in 'field list'". What i'm I doing wrong?

```
SELECT *,  
            p.plays AS pl, 
            m.plays AS mp,
            COUNT(p.sid) frequency,    
FROM        music m
            JOIN plays p
            ON p.sid = m.sid
            INNER JOIN users u
            ON u.uid = m.uid
            INNER JOIN downloads d
            ON d.sid = m.sid        
WHERE       p.time > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY 
            AND p.sid != '' 
            AND m.perms != 'c' 
GROUP       BY m.sid
ORDER       BY frequency DESC
            LIMIT 50
```

Images.

**TABLE: Music**

[image: Music Table]

**TABLE: Plays**

[image: plays table]

Thanks.

Comment: is that column present in table ?

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande, plays is present in both "table" music and table "plays".

Comment: can you share your schema and tables with `SQLFiddle`

Comment: I don't see a column `plays`in table `plays`. You got your answer right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per your table schema you provided in edit . you dont have `Plays` column in `plays` table thats why you getting this error try removing this `p.Plays`

```
SELECT *,  

            m.plays AS mp,
            COUNT(p.sid) frequency,    
FROM        music m
            JOIN plays p
            ON p.sid = m.sid
            INNER JOIN users u
            ON u.uid = m.uid
            INNER JOIN downloads d
            ON d.sid = m.sid        
WHERE       p.time > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY 
            AND p.sid != '' 
            AND m.perms != 'c' 
GROUP       BY m.sid
ORDER       BY frequency DESC
            LIMIT 50
```

Comment: I don't know what was I drinking, lol, but this serves as an answer. I'll accept this.

Comment: @Relm haha !!! sometimes you have to look it from different perspective. may be time to change your drink :P